# git actions save workflow trigger to variable

Tags: github, github-actions

I wrote a Github action workflow of which will be triggered only when some specific files were updated:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    paths:
    ### If a push was applied on one of these files, the CI workflow is triggered.###
    ### I want to know which file triggered the CI workflow and save it to a variable s I can use later in the CI steps ###
    - 'dwh/helm/values-versions.yaml' 
    - 'ai/helm/values-versions.yaml'
    - 'platform/helm/values-versions.yaml'

jobs:
  copy-values-template-to-fluent-bit:
      runs-on: self-hosted
      container:
        image: ghcr.io/***/myImage
        credentials:
          username: ${{ secrets.GHCR_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GHCR_PASS }}
      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: show repo files
          run: |
            pwd
            ls -l
```

I need a way to figure out which file triggered the CI workflow and save it to a variable.

Comment: This is a *GitHub* action, not a Git action. (Git does not have actions, in this sense.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this action [Get All Changed Files](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-all-changed-files):

```yaml
- id: files
  uses: jitterbit/get-changed-files@v1
- run: |
    for changed_file in ${{ steps.files.outputs.all }}; do
      echo "Do something with this ${changed_file} to check if this is you file and set variable."
    done
```